# Application crashing when using ExpandableTextView with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

When I try to add `ScrollView` to my layout as below, my app crashes, though I have one child view inside it. Do I need to include anything else? I am new to Android.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/expandable_text_view"
            app:maxCollapsedLines="1"
            app:animDuration="200"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/expandable_text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#666"
                                />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/expand_collapse"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="16dp"
                />
        </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>

    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></view>
    <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expandable_text_view2"
        app:maxCollapsedLines="1"
        app:animDuration="200"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/expandable_text2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#666"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/expand_collapse2"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            />




        </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>

        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

The error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference at
>   com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView.findViews(ExpandableTextView.java:278)

Comment: Can you please add the logs from Android Studio when this crash occurs? This should highlight where the problem is

Comment: `<view android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></view>` --> `<View ...>`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView.findViews(ExpandableTextView.java:278)

Comment: it crashes because there is a bug in your code. Fixing this bug will prevent crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

You should have only one `ExpandableTextView` per screen, since its implementation relies on the `TextView` id `expandable_text`. You cannot give another name for its `TextView` child, like `expandable_text2`.

**Original Answer**

You have a typo on your `View` widget. You should use `View` starting with a capital "V". Using it with a lowercase "v" will make your app crash in runtime.

Comment: even after removing the view widget, still app is crashing, below is the logcat,
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView.findViews(ExpandableTextView.java:278)